# ConfigService returning String Value even after parsing

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, environment-variables, nestjs

So, here is my NEST JS Basic App.

**./shared/utils/config/index.ts**

```
export default  () => ({
   PORT: parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000,
   TO_PRINT_RESPONSE: JSON.parse(process.env.TO_PRINT_RESPONSE),
});
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import CONFIG from './shared/utils/config/';
@Module({
      imports: [ 
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
          isGlobal: true,
          load: [ CONFIG ],
        })
      ]
      // some more Module Decorator Config
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
      consumer
        .apply(AuthMiddleware)
        .forRoutes({ path: '/someurl', method: RequestMethod.ALL });
      // some more configuration code.
  }
}
```

**main.ts**

```
// AppModule is app.module.ts imported variable
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

async function bootstrap() {
    const app: INestApplication = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
       logger: console,
    });

    const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
    console.log(typeof configService.get<Boolean>('TO_PRINT_RESPONSE'));

    /* this is coming as String even when:
     * 1. I place <Boolean> as a type (I know its of no use, since it does not change the datatype)
     * 2. But in config/index.ts I parsed it in BOOLEAN using JSON.parse()
     */  
}
bootstrap();
```

**.env**

```
 PORT=5000
 TO_PRINT_RESPONSE=true
```

Now:

1. .env is getting loaded via **dotenv** module as written (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration)
2. Kept debug inside **./shared/utils/config/index.ts** and it is getting hit.

So, may someone please tell me, where am I doing wrong in reading the ENV value in proper datatype, when I loaded the JSON in proper format (**./shared/utils/config/index.ts**).

Thanks & Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that Nest's `ConfigService` will not override the values it has read from the environment, hence their types will always default to `string`.

What you can do, however, is to assign the parsed values to different properties in your config-factory:

```
export default  () => ({
   port: parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000,
   toPrintResponse: JSON.parse(process.env.TO_PRINT_RESPONSE),
});
```

If you then access those values, the types will be correct:

```
console.log(typeof configService.get('toPrintResponse')); // prints boolean
console.log(typeof configService.get('port')); // prints number
```

Comment: So, things are good, I am able to get all the values (with datatype) if I make a different named variable, but is there anything, that we can do to override this setting.

Comment: As far as I know there's no way to override those unfortunately.

Comment: I just ran into this issue and have been trying to figure out what is going on here. All my config values are returning as strings, even though I pass a type parameter to get. If this is the intended behavior it makes the config service pretty useless. Why on earth would you ever implement something this way.

Comment: For this, NEST gives the a way to create a SCHEMA out of your ENV's. The option to use is load option in config module options here: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#custom-configuration-files

Using this you can expose your custom config along with process ENV's, and with datatype.

now for getting the value with datatype of the ENV please ask configService to return the value from custom config instead of the process ENV.